# Player position triggering teleports

Tags: java, minecraft-modding, bukkit

I'm developing a Minecraft plugin (bukkit) in which a server admin can create 'portals' - a small region that will teleport any  players who enter it. I have the teleportation sorted and I know how I could define areas that the player's position could be tested against.

This would involve an `ArrayList` containing the zones and then hooking the `PlayerMoveEvent` so that the `ArrayList` is searched each time for a matching portal region.

Although this method would work, I doubt that it would be very efficient when 100+ players are all moving around at the same time. Is there a better way of checking a player position against a set of 'zones' / regions?

Comment: What you are looking for are broad-phase collision detection algorithms. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1616448/broad-phase-collision-detection-methods

Comment: Since it is Minecraft, couldn't you just use hidden teleporting command blocks combined with a redstone clock or custom mob spawner for this?  Though, it might not be as easy and convenient for admins, I suppose.

Answer (score 1):

There is an open source plugin called VoxelPort that does this, see here:
https://github.com/TVPT/VoxelPort/tree/master/src/main/java/com/thevoxelbox/voxelport

It uses Zones as you suggested, and each "Port" calculates whether a player is inside the region & if they are holding the appropriate key. To prevent tons of lag, it has 2 types of ports. Instant ports, and Delayed ports. The delayed ones are used more on our server because they only check if a player is in a zone every so often(Based on set-time). On the server we're on (VoxelBox) it's about every 5 seconds or so.

As for player move events, it stores the data from the event in a HashMap instead of checking every move event. Then a thread "ticks" for when to check players.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the bukkit forums and you might get more replies, but anyway.
Im a bukkit plugin dev myself, although I haven't been on bukkit a while. If you want to find a useful method you should look at the [javadoc](http://jd.bukkit.org/).I had a quick skim through and it seems that would be the only way, unless you changed the behaviour of another block to act as a proximity detector.

Comment: Just relised the java section is dead :O